# Div or P tag stripped out by Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Why is Wordpress stripping out the `<p>` tag?

```
<?php 
  if (the_post_thumbnail_caption()) { 
  echo '<p>' .the_post_thumbnail_caption(). '</p>'; 
}
?>
```

Result should have been shown as `<p>Caption here</p>` but it's shown as:

```
Caption here
```

The

tags are stripped out. Any idea why?

Comment: In what context does the code run? Is it in a shortcode? Is it directly in the template? Is it in a hook?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_caption/

`get_the_post_thumbnail_caption()`

This will return the data as string, so you can then do:

`echo '<p>' . get_the_post_thumbnail_caption() . '</p>';`